# How can I pass data from row to dialog component in react-table?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

This is my first time using react-table, after I decided to redesign a component in my app. I'm almost there, but I found myself stuck while trying to pass some data to a dialog pop-up on button click.

In my previous table design, using MUI Table, I used `array.map()` to render each row entry. Then, all I needed to do was using `props` to pass data to the `Dialog` components, so every action button would load the data from their respective entries (including data not displayed, like `_id`). Now with react-table I don't know how to achieve the same result, due to the logic change. The Edit and Delete buttons are there, they trigger the dialog opening, but my progress ends here.

**Entries.jsx**

```
function Entries(props) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const [openEdit, setOpenEdit] = useState(false);
  const [openDelete, setOpenDelete] = useState(false);

  const handleEdit = () => {
    setOpenEdit(true);
  };

  const handleDelete = () => {
    setOpenDelete(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpenEdit(false);
    setOpenDelete(false);
  };

  const data = props.data;

  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "#",
        id: "row",
        Cell: ({ row }) => {
          return <div>{row.index + 1}</div>;
        },
      },
      {
        Header: "Title",
        accessor: "title",
        className: "column-left",
        Cell: ({ cell: { value }, row: { original } }) => (
          <Link
            sx={{
              fontSize: "14px",
              fontWeight: 500,
              "&:hover": { color: "#00D67E" },
            }}
            color="#fff"
            underline="none"
            style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
            onClick={() => navigate(`/details/${original.movieId}`)}
          >
            {value}
          </Link>
        ),
      },
      {
        Header: "Year",
        accessor: "year",
        className: "column-right",
      },
      {
        Header: "Rating",
        accessor: "details[0].rating",
        className: "column-right",
        Cell: ({ cell: { value } }) => (
          <Rating
            size="small"
            value={value}
            readOnly
            emptyIcon={<StarIcon fontSize="inherit" />}
          />
        ),
      },
      {
        Header: "Watched",
        accessor: "date",
        className: "column-right",
        Cell: ({ cell: { value } }) => format(new Date(value), "MMM dd, yyyy"),
      },
      {
        Header: "View Count",
        accessor: "details[0].view_count",
        className: "column-right",
      },
      {
        Header: "Review",
        accessor: "details[0].review",
        className: "column-right",
        Cell: ({ cell: { value } }) =>
          !value ? null : <CheckIcon color="primary" />,
      },
      {
        Header: "Actions",
        className: "column-right",
        Cell: () => (
          <div>
            <IconButton
              aria-label="edit"
              style={{ color: "#e0e0e0" }}
              onClick={handleEdit}
            >
              <EditIcon fontSize="small" />
            </IconButton>

            <IconButton
              aria-label="delete"
              style={{ color: "#e0e0e0", paddingRight: 0 }}
              onClick={handleDelete}
            >
              <DeleteIcon fontSize="small" />
            </IconButton>
          </div>
        ),
      },
    ],
    []
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {/* TABLE */}
      <CustomTable columns={columns} data={data} />

      {/* DIALOGS */}
      <EditDialog
        isOpen={openEdit}
        onClose={handleClose}
        id={data._id}
        movieId={data.movieId}
        date={data.date}
        rating={data.details[0].rating}
        review={data.details[0].review}
        onUpdate={props.onUpdate}
      />

      <DeleteDialog
        isOpen={openDelete}
        onClose={handleClose}
        title="Delete this entry?"
        message={
          <span>
            <strong>
              {data.title} ({data.date})
            </strong>{" "}
            will be removed. This action cannot be undone.
          </span>
        }
        onRemove={() => {
          props.onRemove(data._id, data.movieId);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Entries;
```

Later on I even tried something to mimic the logic of my previous design, since the mapping is handled by the `rows.map((row) => { prepareRow(row) }` in my `CustomTable.jsx` component. Then I came up with this:

```
{
        Header: "Actions",
        className: "column-right",
        Cell: () => (
          <div>
            <IconButton
              aria-label="edit"
              style={{ color: "#e0e0e0" }}
              onClick={({row}) => {
                handleEdit();

                return (
                  <EditDialog
                    isOpen={openEdit}
                    onClose={handleClose}
                    id={row._id}
                    movieId={row.movieId}
                    date={row.date}
                    rating={row.details[0].rating}
                    review={row.details[0].review}
                    onUpdate={props.onUpdate}
                  />
                );
              }}
            >
              <EditIcon fontSize="small" />
            </IconButton>

            <IconButton
              aria-label="delete"
              style={{ color: "#e0e0e0", paddingRight: 0 }}
              onClick={handleDelete}
            >
              <DeleteIcon fontSize="small" />
            </IconButton>
          </div>
        ),
      }
```

But it didn't work either. It stops right at the first prop and throws an error saying it can't read properties `row._id`. That was my last shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is simple, you can store the selected row to the state and then use it in your Edit and Delete components. Try this

```
function Entries(props) { 
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [openEdit, setOpenEdit] = useState(false);
  const [openDelete, setOpenDelete] = useState(false);
  const [selectedRow, setSelectedRow] = useState();

  const handleEdit = (row) => {
    setOpenEdit(true);
    setSelectedRow(row);
  };

  const handleDelete = (row) => {
    setOpenDelete(true);
    setSelectedRow(row);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpenEdit(false);
    setOpenDelete(false);
    setSelectedRow();
  };

  const data = props.data;

  const columns = useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        Header: "#",
        id: "row",
        Cell: ({ row }) => {
          return <div>{row.index + 1}</div>;
        }
      },
      {
        Header: "Title",
        accessor: "title",
        className: "column-left",
        Cell: ({ cell: { value }, row: { original } }) => (
          <Link
            sx={{
              fontSize: "14px",
              fontWeight: 500,
              "&:hover": { color: "#00D67E" }
            }}
            color="#fff"
            underline="none"
            style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
            onClick={() => navigate(`/details/${original.movieId}`)}
          >
            {value}
          </Link>
        )
      },
      {
        Header: "Year",
        accessor: "year",
        className: "column-right"
      },
      {
        Header: "Rating",
        accessor: "details[0].rating",
        className: "column-right",
        Cell: ({ cell: { value } }) => (
          <Rating
            size="small"
            value={value}
            readOnly
            emptyIcon={<StarIcon fontSize="inherit" />}
          />
        )
      },
      {
        Header: "Watched",
        accessor: "date",
        className: "column-right",
        Cell: ({ cell: { value } }) => format(new Date(value), "MMM dd, yyyy")
      },
      {
        Header: "View Count",
        accessor: "details[0].view_count",
        className: "column-right"
      },
      {
        Header: "Review",
        accessor: "details[0].review",
        className: "column-right",
        Cell: ({ cell: { value } }) =>
          !value ? null : <CheckIcon color="primary" />
      },
      {
        Header: "Actions",
        className: "column-right",
        Cell: ({ row }) => (
          <div>
            <IconButton
              aria-label="edit"
              style={{ color: "#e0e0e0" }}
              onClick={() => handleEdit(row.original)}
            >
              <EditIcon fontSize="small" />
            </IconButton>

            <IconButton
              aria-label="delete"
              style={{ color: "#e0e0e0", paddingRight: 0 }}
              onClick={() => handleEdit(row.original)}
            >
              <DeleteIcon fontSize="small" />
            </IconButton>
          </div>
        )
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {/* TABLE */}
      <CustomTable columns={columns} data={data} />

      {/* DIALOGS */}
        <EditDialog
          isOpen={openEdit}
          onClose={handleClose}
          id={selectedRow?._id}
          movieId={selectedRow?.movieId}
          date={selectedRow?.date}
          rating={selectedRow?.details[0]?.rating}
          review={selectedRow?.details[0]?.review}
          onUpdate={props.onUpdate}
        />

        <DeleteDialog
          isOpen={openDelete}
          onClose={handleClose}
          title="Delete this entry?"
          message={
            <span>
              <strong>
                {selectedRow?.title} ({selectedRow?.date})
              </strong>{" "}
              will be removed. This action cannot be undone.
            </span>
          }
          onRemove={() => {
            props.onRemove(selectedRow?._id, selectedRow?.movieId);
          }}
        />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Entries;
```

Comment: It worked brilliantly! Thanks! Just some question, if you don't mind: while studying your solution I noticed that if you remove the `openEdit && selectedRow &&` part, the app will try to immediately trigger the dialog pop-up on rendering the page (and will crash, sure, because there will be no data loaded to the states yet). Why is that? Shouldn't it trigger the action only when `openEdit` is set after the click? I didn't understand why you needed to include the conditional and why it only works if it's there.

Comment: I don't this the dialog tries to open, but you are you are passing `undefined` value for all its props, as a result when it tries to access values say for example `selectedRow.details[0].rating` it will fail since `undefined` do not have any `details[0].rating`. You can try removing the condition and instead of `selectedRow.details[0].rating` pass `selectedRow?.details[0]?.rating`

Comment: I will edit my answer with the updated props, try that

Comment: Have edited, you should also handle for `undefined` values for the props inside your components

Comment: Oh, now I got it. I didn't think that it would try to pass and load the props before being called by the button click. So that's why it was failing. Now that I think about it, it totally makes sense, since the component will be already there (although hidden) if the conditional isn't present. Again, thanks =)